# Move unallocated partition in Gparted

Tags: 17.10, gparted

I have Ubuntu 17.10 on my PC, and I have installed `gparted`. But it seems that I can't add the unallocated space to `/dev/sda4`, because I can't move it down.

[image]

I have looked online, but found nothing.

Comment: You have to boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB to do what you want. You can't change live/mounted partitions.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so, if you installed Gparted in your "mounted" system, then no, you can't move that partition. You need to boot from a live-usb session. Once inside there, you can move that partition (being that it is going to take awhile to move it, bit/byte by bit/byte). Another thing you'll experience, is when you move it, linux may or may not boot back up. Depending on how your GRUB config is setup. You may have to reinstall grub through the live-usb. Googling that procedure is available. I've had to do that myself.